# Difference between training and testing accuracy+ Tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

The code in this tensorflow [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) uses this section of the code to calculate the validation accuracy right?

```
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": eval_data},
      y=eval_labels,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)
```

**Question:** So if I had to calculate the training set accuracy that is to see if my model is overfitting my training set data, if I changed the value of **"x"** to **train_data** and feed the training data for testing as well, Would it give me the training set accuracy?

If not, how do I check if my model is overfitting my dataset?

How does the number of steps affect the accuracy? 
Like if I have trained it for 20000 steps and then if I train it for another 100. Why does it change the accuracy? Is it since the weights are being calculated all over again? Would it be advisable to do something like this  then?

```
mnist_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=20000,
      hooks=[logging_hook])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you have 3 datasets, 1 for training, 1 for validation and 1 for testing. All these datasets have to be unique, an image of the training set may not occur in the validation or test set, etc. You train with the training set and after each epoch, you validate the model with the validation data. The optimizers will always try to update the weights to perfectly classify the training data, the training accuracy will therefore get very high (>90). The validation data is data the model has never seen before, and its done after each epoch (or x amount of steps) to show how well the model reacts to data is hasn't seen before, this shows how well the model will improve overtime.

The more you train, the higher the training accuracy will become, since the optimizer will do its best to get that value to 100%. The validation data, that does not update the weights, also increases overtime, but not continuously. While the training accuracy keeps improving, the validation accuracy might stop improving. The moment the validation accuracy decreases over time, well then you're overfitting. This means that the model is focusing too much on the training data, and that it can't classify another character correctly if it differs from the training set.

At the end of all the training you use a test set, this will determine the actual accuracy of your model on new data.

@xmacz: I cannot add comments yet, only answers so I just update my answer. Yes, I checked the source code, your first lines of code tests the model on test data

Comment: Okay. Also, please see the first two lines of the post. The tutorial makes use of the MNIST database of 60K images and creates a training set of 50k and test set of 10k images respectively. The accuracy being printed at the end of the code execution is the accuracy of the model on the Test set of 10k right?

Comment: Please see this question as well if possible. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884631/tensorflow-model-accuracy

Answer (score 0):

The `evaluate` is just a function which does some numerical activities to the input data and produces some output. If you use it for testing data it should give the testing accuracy and if you input the training data it should output the training accuracy.

At the end of the day it is just mathematics. What the output is **intuitively**, is something that you would have to ascertain.

Comment: So I can detect overfitting via doing this right? Also I had a small query regarding the number of steps which I just put in. Could you please address that as well?

Answer (score 0):

How to know whether your model is overfitting is something you do while training the model. You have to set apart another set called validation dataset which is different from the test and training sets. A typical split of datasets is 70%-20%-10% for training, testing and validating respectively.

During the training, every n steps you test your model on the validation dataset. During the first iterations the score on your validation set will get better but at some point it will get worse. You can use this information to stop your training when your model starts to overfit but doing it right is an art. You could for instance stop after 5 tests that your accuracy has been decreasing consecutively, because sometimes you can see that it gets worse but in the next test it gets better. It's hard to say, it depends on many factors.

Regarding to your second question, iterating another 100 steps could make your model better or worse, depending on whether it's overfitting or not, so I'm afraid that question doesn't have a clear answer. The weights will rarely stop changing because the iterations/steps are "moving" them, for good or for bad. Again, it's difficult to say how to get good results, but you could try early stopping using a validation set, as I've mentioned before.

Comment: Okay. Also, please see the first two lines of the post. The tutorial makes use of the MNIST database of 60K images and creates a training set of 50k and test set of 10k images respectively. The accuracy being printed at the end of the code execution is the accuracy of the model on the Test set of 10k right?