# Tensorflow model accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

My model which I have trained on a set of 29K images for 36 classes and validated on 7K images. The model has a training accuracy of 94.59% and validation accuracy of 95.72%
It has been created for OCR on digits and characters. I know the amount of images for training on 36 classes might not be sufficient. I'm not certain what to infer from these results.

**Question:** Is this a good result? Should the testing accuracy always be greater than training accuracy? Is my model overfitting?

**Question:** How would I know if my model was overfitting? I'm assuming a very high training accuracy and very low testing accuracy would indicate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 95% is rather good for 36 classes. If your validation accuracy is higher than training accuracy, you are underfitting. You can run some more epochs, until your training accuracy is *a bit* higher than validation accuracy.
2. Exactly, if training accuracy is much higher, you are overfitting.

Comment: What should I do in case my training accuracy does not increase?
I just ran the model over a couple more iterations and it's accuracy fell to 94.37% and the validation accuracy became 94.29% What should I do in such a case?

Comment: If you have insufficient amount of images, that could be the reason. You should try data augmentation. Also, one of the technics is to just copy data in classes which are problematic.

Comment: What would be an ideal percentage of accuracy for training and testing? I know it depends on a lot of factors but assuming my training accuracy is 95% how much should my validation accuracy be around for the model to be a good one?

Also, a 95% training accuracy indicates that my model has analyzed the training data well? I feel these standalone percentages mean nothing and the training and validation accuracy is relative. Am I wrong here?

Comment: In my opinion, 2-4% overfitting is good. If your dataset is similar to ImageNet images, you can just compare your accuracy with performance of different models on ImageNet. If it is different (medical, satellite and so on images, not just real-world photos) it is much harder to say, but generally, for multi-label classification, if you are above 90%, you model is OK, 95-98% is good.

Answer (score 0):

1. The training accuracy should always be higher than the testing accuracy/ validation accuracy. This is because your model has to be good on the data that it is provided to be able to predict unknown datas. However, it also happens sometimes and the reason could be
   a. The test test wasn't randomly selected or was randomly selected but turned out to be
   favourable one (a coincidence).
   b. Your Model is very generalized and in combination with the first problem.
2. Check the learning curve first, Your case is rare in which the training accuracy is smaller. Solution may be more data or More complex models or more epochs (Solution to underfitting)